# How to view TV Tuner component input with OpenCV?

Tags: opencv, video-capture

I'm trying to use my tvtuner instead of a webcam with opencv.

The problem is that by default cvCaptureFromCAM(0) gives me the tv channel of the tv tuner, but what I actually want the input from my the RCA input of the tv tuner.

I have tried usingcvCaptureFromCAM(-1) to check if there are additional camera devices found within the tvtuner, but it only gives me the general tvtuner as an option.

Is there a way to change the channel of the input?

Answer (score 0):

Probably not.

In Linux (and Windows is similar), the OpenCV `cvCaptureFromCAM()` only recognizes one input for each tuner/framegrabber/webcam.  If your device shows up as multiple logical devices, then you can use the parameter of `cvCaptureFromCAM()` to select which logical device to use.

For example: if you have:

```
/dev/video
/dev/video0 <-- tv tuner, tuner input 
/dev/video1 <-- tv tuner, rca input
```

`cvCaptureFromCAM(0)` will use `/dev/video0` and
`cvCaptureFromCAM(1)` will use `/dev/video1`.

What might work is if you use some other program such as mythtv or tvtime (or something else on windows) to change the input for your tuner to your RCA input and then try running opencv again.